# Mock Observable service on ngOnInit

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

PS This is first time I will be writing test cases.

Env details:
 - Angular 4.4.3

**in component**

```
currentToken: string;

constructor(private tokenService: TokenService){}

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.tokenService.getCurrentToken().subscribe((token: string) => {
      this.currentToken = token;
   });
}
```

**in TokenService**

```
export class TokenService {
   constructor(private router: Router) { }

   getCurrentToken(): Observable<string> {
      const token: string = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
      if (token) {
         return Observable.of(token);
      }else {
         this.router.navigate(['home']);
      }
   }
}
```

**In spec.ts**

```
describe("AccountComponent" , () => {
   let component: AccountComponent;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<AccountComponent>;

   beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [],
        declaration: [ TokenService ]
      }).compileComponents();
   }));

   beforeEach(() => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AccountComponent);
     component = fixture.createInstance;
     fixture.detectChanges();
     component.ngOnInit();
   });

   it("should create", () => {
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });
});
```

This is simple test which will come when i used angular cli. As you may be already know that I am getting error like below.

*"Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"*

This is common kind of method which i will writing in all new component.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a `FakeService` as below,

- Define a fake class with the method returning some string.
- The class
- Inject the provider in the `beforeEach()`
- In the `it` block modify it to the `toBeDefined()` as the component cannot be truthy

  ```
  describe("AccountComponent" , () => {
     let component: AccountComponent;
     let fixture: ComponentFixture<AccountComponent>;
     let tokenService : TokenService;
     class FakeTokenService {
          getCurrentToken(){
              Observable.of('some string')
          }
     }

     beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [],
          declaration: [ ],
          providers: [
              { provide: TokenService, useClass: FakeTokenService }
          ]
        }).compileComponents();
     }));

     beforeEach(() => {
       fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AccountComponent);
       component = fixture.createInstance;
       fixture.detectChanges();
       fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TokenService);
     });

     it("should create", () => {
       expect(component).toBeTruthy();
     });
  });
  ```